# jQuery Functional Looping : Why does Shakira repeats the kisses as new person kissed her?

Tags: javascript, jquery

*See the demo of my question here*: [jsFiddle Question Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hxzLF/)

Is not this unfair?

When first Kisser (any one of A, B, C or D) kisses Shkira, she gives one kiss.
And, she gives 2 kisses when Second.
3 to the third and so on.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var kisses = 0;

    $("#main").delegate(".kisser","click",function(){
      $("#inner").css("display","block");
      $("#hint").css("display","none");
      foo();
    });


    function foo(){
      $("#innerClicker").click(function(){
        kisses++;
        $(".results").html("Kissed <h1>" + kisses + "</h1> times. <br />");
        $("#inner").css("display","none");
        $("#hint").css("display","block");

      }); 
    }

    });
```

Comment: Don't add a new event handler inside an event handler.

Comment: @FelixKling Is  there a solution for this approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what the expected outcome is / how the code is supposed to work overall, so I can't tell.

Comment: @FelixKling The code wants a single kiss addition when one person kisses. In short, it wants Justice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are binding  `$("#innerClicker")`  the event every clicked element

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var kisses = 0;

    $("#main").delegate(".kisser", "click", function () {
        $("#inner").css("display", "block");
        $("#hint").css("display", "none");
        foo();

    });


    function foo() {
        kisses++;
    }

    $("#innerClicker").click(function () {
        if (kisses) {
            $(".results").html("Kissed <h1>" + kisses + "</h1> times. <br />");
            $("#inner").css("display", "none");
            $("#hint").css("display", "block");
        }
    });


});
```

### [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hxzLF/2/)

**NOTE :**  IF you bind the element every clicked .it will be added  and fired how many times you were clicked  ,and also use `on` method instead of `delegate` ,the delegate method was deprecated in new version of jquery